# Cannot open file for reading

Tags: java, debugging, file-io

I am using console IO to read file and display it in my IDE window ( I am using Netbeanz)

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {  
       String data;
       Scanner myscan = new Scanner(new File("foo.txt"));

       while ( myscan.hasNextLine())
       {
           data = myscan.nextLine();
           System.out.println(data);
       }

       myscan.close();
    }
}
```

For some reason , i cannot open the file : `foo.txt` though i have placed it in the same folder as my application

Here is a picture of where i have placed `foo.txt`

[image]

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: foo.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:21)
```

**How do i resolve this problem and what is happening ??**

Comment: Do you have an error stacktrace that might explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the most likely cause is file not found.

When you open a file, it looks from your Working Directory.

I think for netbeans that is at the root of the project.

In such a case, the real filename is `src/javaapplication1/foo.txt` rather than `foo.txt`.

If you just need that file, and do not need to point to any file, you can embed it into the application and read it using an input stream.

Answer (score 1):

`File` takes absolute path. You can try this

```
InputStream is = JavaApplication1.class.getResourceAsStream("foo.txt");
myscan = new Scanner(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       URL url = JavaApplication1.class.getResource("sample.txt");
        File f = new File(url.toURI());
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(f);
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }
```